# Failed to publish globe service on ArcGIS Server. Error 001369

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, web-service, arcglobe, globe

I'm trying to publish a globe service on our ArcGIS Server and in ArcGlobe I get this error message

> "*Failed to publish service.*"

---> Went to Results: 
[h=1]001369 :

> Failed to create the service.[/h] [h=2]Description[/h]The creation of
>   the service failed. This is a generic error. Many different conditions
>   could cause this failure. Check the server logs for the specific
>   issue.

[h=2]Solution[/h]Check the server logs for the specific issue.

--> Went to ArcGIS Server Logs:

> SEVERE    22.08.2013, 10:15:20    Failed to construct instance of service
>   'glob_4.GlobeServer'. Server SEVERE   22.08.2013, 10:15:20    Failed to
>   initialize server object 'glob_4': 0x80030003: null   Server
>   SEVERE    22.08.2013, 10:15:20    (null)  glob_4.GlobeServer

Unfortunately I really don't know how to solve that. The service is published (I can see it on the server) but apparently it cannot start. I also tried saving a service definition file and then publishing it on the server-> same problem.

So thanks for any advice.

PS: We use ArcGIS Server 10.1 on Linux

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but I think the reason why I cannot publish the globe service is because we don't have the ArcGIS Image Extension for Server. "The ArcGIS Image extension is also required when publishing a globe document containing a mosaic dataset or raster layer"

My globe service contained a polygon feature class, and I extruded the features.

Not only we don't have the Image Extension but apparently it doesn't run on Linux either.

So I'm not sure if this is the cause, but please support or contradict my answer.

Comment: we've got the Image extension. so I was wrong.